# Could not add ppa:neon/kf5 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: kde, ppa

I'm trying to install the latest vesion of KDE.

```
~ $> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:neon/kf5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

It seems that ppa:neon/kf5 does not exist?

Is there any other way to install the kde 5?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
3.13.0-40-genericx86_64 x86_64

Comment: I've left a comment on that post. I'm afraid this is not a duplicate question, since the ppa mentioned in that answer simply does not work.

Comment: See the project neon page for the correct ppa name:  https://launchpad.net/~neon/+archive/ubuntu/ppa